# HLA Hello, World - Assembler Error

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler, hla

I've started going through Randall Hyde's "The Art of Assembly" to start whetting my palate. I downloaded and installed HLA 1.38 (which I need for 64-bit support) from [here](http://net.pku.edu.cn/~course/cs201/2003/mirrorWebster.cs.ucr.edu/Page_hla/0_hla_dnld.html) , and wrote the Hello, World program as described in both the documentation listed there and in the book above.

```
program helloWorld;
#include ("stdlib.hhf");
begin helloWorld;
    stdout.put("Hello, World!", nl);
end helloWorld;
```

when I run `hla helloWorld.hla`, I get the following error message: 
`helloWorld.asm:66: Error: ambiguous operand size or operands invalid for 'push'`

The Assembly line in question reads:

```
pushd   0       ;/* No Dynamic Link. */
```

As I am as green as can be with assembly language, I have no idea how to make this work. I'm assuming that there's a discrepancy between my version of gas and HLA 1.38. So the question remains: what now?

Edit: I tried compiling just the 'program', 'begin', and 'end' directives (removing the possibility of it being something with the stdlib), and get the same result with a program that does effectively nothing.

I am on 64-bit CrunchBang Linux.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to learn **assembler**, I would really advise dropping HLA and this badly named book. Usually, you want to use assembler so that you have total control over the generated code. HLA takes it away. And if you want a more high-level language to not bother with register allocation and pushes and pops, there are much better choices available.

As for your question, it seems the asm generated by HLA is not of valid syntax for GAS. Since it's mainly targeting Windows, it would seem Linux is not very well tested. You could try either adding "`.intel_syntax noprefix`" at the top of the file, or adding $ to all immediate value (such as 0), but I suspect there won't be a trivial fix.

Comment: HLA is meant to serve as "training wheels" from high level languages to assembly languages, not a replacement for them. Thanks for the insight into a possible fix. I'll see what can be done.

Comment: I agree with Igor. HLA will teach you nothing useful besides the things you have already known long before.

Comment: There is an alternative: fasm. This can assemble 64 bit code, and doesn't need a linker. I use it routinely to cross-assembler 64 bit Windows(!) executables on Linux. I cite myself: "assembler programming is dancing on a rope. Intel wants to hide where the rope is.". This is even more true for hla. Randall Hyde has done an excellent job in documenting Windows system calls. That is enough for eternal fame. hla not so much.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case anybody else trying to break into Assembly stumbles upon this thread: HLA is a fantastic middle step for people who are familiar with higher level languages and would like to step closer to the machine without swan diving on day 1.

It, however, is NOT a replacement for actual Assembly language, as Tom stated. i.e once you get comfortable with HLA and a few of the commands of Assembly, THEN move to real Assembly Language. It will be far less daunting (personal experience)